# Is it possible to create an array of Label[] without setting the initial array size Label[22]

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

Is it possible to create an array of `Label[]` without setting the initial array size `Label[22]`?

```
Label[] l = new Label[22];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    l[i] = new Label(String.valueOf(i));
    l[i].setMinSize(100, 32);
    vbox.getChildren().add(l[i]);
}
```

Comment: At some point, you MUST define the size of an array, that's how they work, if you want something more dynamic, then you should use some kind of `List`, like `ArrayList`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply @MadProgrammer. How can I implement dynamic **Labels** via **Lists** instead of an **Array**? Could you please give me a small illustration? I'm willing to accept it as an answer.

Comment: You just have to think of a `List` as been a "dynamic array" - Start by having a look at [the Collections Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: Take a look at the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/90/collections/386/declaring-an-arraylist-and-adding-objects#t=201701152349482702294)